# Will TFS 2013 and VS 2013 using Test Impact Analysis work with NUnit

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration, build-process

I am using TFS 2013 and VS 2013.  In my CI Builds, I want to enable Test Impact Analysis.  However, I am using NUnit.  Is it possible to use NUnit with Test Impact Analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say it that from what I've seen Test Impact Analysis will not work with NUnit, only MSTest.  I don't think this story has changed with TFS 2013 Update 2 either.